# How to refresh a dataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, odbc, datasource, ibm-midrange

I have a problem refreshing a DataGridView control after `Insert` or `Update`. The source code:

Get all rows from table in datatable and set to the datasource:

```
Dim dt1 as DataTable = GetData("SELECT * FROM CLAIMSTATE ")
dataGrid.DataSource = dt1
```

Update Event if ID is valued, and Insert if it isn't:

```
Private Sub dataGrid_RowLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataGrid.RowLeave

Dim row As DataGridViewRow = CType(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex)
  Dim query As New StringBuilder("")
  If row.Cells(0).Value & "" = "" Then
    query.Append("INSERT INTO CLAIMSTATE ")
    query.Append("(CST_CODE, CST_LABEL, CST_POINTS)")
    query.Append("VALUES ")
    query.Append("(?, ?, ?)")
  Else
    query.Append("Update CLAIMSTATE ")
    query.Append("SET CST_CODE = ?, ")
    query.Append("CST_LABEL = ?, ")
    query.Append("CST_POINTS = ? ")
    query.Append("WHERE CST_ID = ? ")
  End If
  Dim command As New OdbcCommand(query.ToString(), con)
  command.Parameters.Add("@cst_code", OdbcType.Char).Value = row.Cells(1).Value
  command.Parameters.Add("@cst_label", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = row.Cells(2).Value
  command.Parameters.Add("@cst_points", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = row.Cells(3).Value
  command.Parameters.Add("@cst_id", OdbcType.BigInt).Value = row.Cells(0).Value

  Dim res As Integer = ExecuteNonQuery(command)
End Sub

Public Function GetData(ByRef sqlQuery As String) As DataTable
    Dim command As New OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, con)
    Try
      If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.ConnectionString = conString
        con.Open()
      End If
      Using dr As OdbcDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Load(dr)
        Return dt
      End Using
      'con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.Message)
      con.Close()
      Return Null
    End Try
  End Function

Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByRef command As OdbcCommand) As Integer
Dim result As Integer = 0
If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
  con.ConnectionString = conString
  con.Open()
End If
'Dim command As New OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, conn)
Try
  'command.Connection = con
  'Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand( sqlQuery, conn)
  result = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch
  result = 0
  If con IsNot Nothing Then
    con.Close()
    command.Dispose()
  End If
Finally
  command.Dispose()
End Try
Return result
End Function
```

I tried to get all records from the table and set the datasource again at the end of the method but it doesn't work.

If I put the code:

```
dataGrid.Rows.Clear()
dataGrid.Columns.Clear()
dt1 = GetData("SELECT * FROM CLAIMSTATE ")
dataGrid.DataSource = dt1
```

on end of event method RowLeave I recive this error:

> "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>   SetCurrentCellAddressCore function"

on dataGrid.Rows.Clear(), but if  I remove the line codes Rows.Clear() and Columns.Clear(), the debug cursor after execute dataGrid.DataSource = dt1 return to begin of event method an execute some code again and after I recive the some error "...reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function"!

Help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this problem I use OdbcDataAdapter. I save all changes with adapter.Update(dataTable) and after I fill the datatable again: adapter.fill(dataTable).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# class I have that I use to connect search my GridView. What you need should be similar I would think.

```
    protected void lbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            odsInbox.FilterExpression =
                string.Format("(l_name LIKE '*{0}*') OR (f_name LIKE '*{0}*') OR (title LIKE '*{0}*')",
                txtSearch.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            odsInbox.FilterExpression = string.Empty;
        }

        gvInbox.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lbClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        odsInbox.FilterExpression = string.Empty;
        txtSearch.Text = "";
        gvInbox.DataBind();
    }
```

I hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: The DataSource on DataGridView don't have the methods Clear() and Add(). Anybody have other ideas how I can do refresh to datagridview?

Comment: I found this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760657/failure-to-validate-but-cannot-remove-in-datagridview
How I can write this in vb.net:
BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { dataGrid.DataSource = dt1; }));

Comment: @wertyk I'm sorry. GridView... not ReportViewer. I'll update the question for that.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a binding with table :(